Should tags be plural whenever applicable?
Apparently we are introducing a lot of tags using the plural form, for instance
nouns, verbs, tenses, foreign-words, ...
but I've already spotted one in a singular form
homograph
I like plural the most since it better qualifies a category, i.e. we are talking about nouns, as opposed to about a noun.
Should we set this as a standard and correct get rid of singular tags, when the plural version is applicable?

I would rather use the plural with tags, but (in some cases) the singular could be more appropriate. For example, ELU uses definite-article because there is just a single definite article in English, and undefinite-article since an is considered a variant of a used in front of words starting with a vocalic pronunciation.
Maybe there are similar cases for Italian too, and in those cases I would use the singular, even if using the plural is what I consider the default.

The ELU stack has the tag "homograph", singular, along with many others that are in the plural form. Moreover, they calmly use "analogy", singular, but "differences", plural. IMHO, the plural form is strongly preferable for any new tags but there is no need to force it.

Agreed. Still acknowledging this as "standard" would allow an easier synonymization policy.
